# Sortable Multi Column Drag and Drop without Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am looking to implement a sortable (ordering) drag and drop between columns as well as in column. I looked all over internet to find any example that does not use a library for it. I'd love to implement it in VueJS, however, any examples are welcome.

It should basically function like JIRA, where you have TODO and IN PROGRESS columns for example, you can order them by priority in the column itself, or move it to another column.

The reason, why I do not want to use any library is because I want to build my own complex functionalities. I also do not wanna fork existing github libraries to modify them. I'd love any suggestions!

Comment: The reason you're not going to find any examples that don't use a library is because DND is a very complex functionality that requires a lot of code. However, I wrote [this implementation](https://github.com/Pamblam/ez-drag-n-drop) and it's relatively simple at less than 500 lines. The source code is very well documented and there are examples as well that may be helpful.

Comment: I totally agree its very complex! Thanks I'll check it out now!